# How do I get console input in spidermonkey JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, input, console, spidermonkey

I'm currently using spidermonkey to run my JavaScript code. I'm wondering if there's a function to get input from the console similar to how Python does this:

```
var = raw_input()
```

Or in C++:

```
std::cin >> var;
```

I've looked around and all I've found so far is how to get input from the browser using the `prompt()` and `confirm()` functions.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Good old `readline();`.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Introduction_to_the_JavaScript_shell#readline.28.29) (archive).

Comment: I can't seem to use when using node.js .. 
Any idea ?

Comment: See the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26683734/how-can-i-take-console-input-from-a-user-in-node-js

Answer (score 17):

In plain JavaScript, simply use `response = readline()` after printing a prompt.

In Node.js, you'll need to use the [readline module](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html): `const readline = require('readline')`

Comment: `        var x = readline();
                ^

TypeError: readline is not a function
` after adding require at the top of the file

Comment: Also had the same problem.

Comment: That's weirder than ever.

Comment: readline does not work the same in node. you need something like this: const readline = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
})
readline.question("what's your name? ", name => {
  console.log(`Hello ${name}`);
  readline.close();
});

Comment: @kDar I prefer to do 
name => { readline.close(); console.log(name); }
In my case, your version doesn't show input while typing.
Anyway, thanks for your comment

Answer (score 15):

As you mentioned, [`prompt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) works for browsers all the way back to IE:

```
var answer = prompt('question', 'defaultAnswer');
```

[image: prompt in IE]

For Node.js > v7.6, you can use [`console-read-write`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/console-read-write), which is a wrapper around the low-level [`readline`](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) module:

```
const io = require('console-read-write');

async function main() {
  // Simple readline scenario
  io.write('I will echo whatever you write!');
  io.write(await io.read());

  // Simple question scenario
  io.write(`hello ${await io.ask('Who are you?')}!`);

  // Since you are not blocking the IO, you can go wild with while loops!
  let saidHi = false;
  while (!saidHi) {
    io.write('Say hi or I will repeat...');
    saidHi = await io.read() === 'hi';
  }

  io.write('Thanks! Now you may leave.');
}

main();
// I will echo whatever you write!
// > ok
// ok
// Who are you? someone
// hello someone!
// Say hi or I will repeat...
// > no
// Say hi or I will repeat...
// > ok
// Say hi or I will repeat...
// > hi
// Thanks! Now you may leave.
```

***Disclosure*** I'm author and maintainer of console-read-write

For SpiderMonkey, simple `readline` as suggested by [@MooGoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/375394/moogoo) and [@Zaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/405550/zaz).

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like `process.argv`, that is if you are using `node.js` to run the program.

`console.log(process.argv)` => Would print an array containing

```sh
[                                                                                                                                                                                          
  '/usr/bin/node',                                                                                                                                                                         
  '/home/user/path/filename.js',                                                                                                                                            
  'your_input'                                                                                                                                                                                   
]
```

You get the user provided input via array index, i.e., `console.log(process.argv[3])` This should provide you with the input which you can store.

**Example:**

```js
var somevariable = process.argv[3]; // input one
var somevariable2 = process.argv[4]; // input two

console.log(somevariable);
console.log(somevariable2);
```

If you are building a command-line program then the npm package [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs) would be really helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Node.js has built-in [readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline) module.

one example:

```js
const readline = require('readline')
const rl = readline.createInterface({
   input: process.stdin,
   output: process.stdout,
});
rl.question(`Are you sure? (yes/no): `, async answer => {
   if (answer.toLocaleLowerCase() === 'yes') {
     console.log('processing...');
   }
   else {
     console.log('aborting...');
   }
});
```