# how to asking questions in nodejs in command line

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface

in ruby we can do it like this

```
print "How old are you? "
age = gets.chomp()
print "How tall are you? "
height = gets.chomp()
print "How much do you weigh? "
weight = gets.chomp()

puts "So, you're #{age} years old, #{height} tall and #{weight} heavy."
```

it will like this

[image]

but how to do it in nodejs?

Comment: http://nodejs.org/api/readline.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Taken from the node.js documentation of [`readline`](http://nodejs.org/api/readline.html):

```
var readline = require('readline');

var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.question("What do you think of node.js? ", function(answer) {
  console.log("Thank you for your valuable feedback:", answer);

  rl.close();
});
```

Comment: Note that this requires node `>=0.10`

Comment: what about if i want to ask more than one question how can i achieve this?

Comment: @NwawelAIroume https://stackoverflow.com/a/8129748/894402