# how can we write a perfect menu driven program using switch case in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, switch-statement, console-application, readline

I want to write something like this

```
var rl = readline.createInterface({
input: process.stdin,
output: process.stdout,
});
r1.setprompt('press 1 to load fle, press 2 to exit');
rl.prompt();

rl.on('line', (line) => {

switch(line.trim()) {
  case '1':
    r1.setPrompt('Enter file name to add');
    r1.prompt()
    r1.on('line',(filename)=>{
        settings = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8'));
    });
    break;
    case '2':
    console.log('Exit');
    process.exit(0);
    break;
  default:
    console.log(`Invalid command '${line.trim()}'`);
    break;
   }
 rl.prompt();
 }).on('close', () => {
process.exit(0);
});
```

I want the menu to be flashed again and again until user selects option 2.
what I've written is wrong ,because r1 is undefined in the switch case.
Is there any other correct way to achieve it.

Comment: how are you defining r1?

Comment: hi @meyer9, const readline = require('readline'); and then I've written it in a code.

Comment: that's not r1. something like `var r1 = something`

Comment: I recommend you to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128578/reading-value-from-console-interactively).

Comment: Hi @MUT, But the problem prevails, coz any variable declared outside is undefined in the switch case statement.

Comment: @MUT it has worked... thank you...