# Is it possible to capture rebol console line by line like in nodejs?

Tags: rebol

I'd like to capture rebol console input line by line so as to act upon it in realtime like in nodejs with readline function : [Reading value from console, interactively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128578/reading-value-from-console-interactively)

Is this possible in rebol ?

Comment: Writing a repl is classically done with  a combination of `forever` and `ask`. There's more than one way to do it of course..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe like

```
until [name: ask "What's your name? " also name = "noname" print ["nice to meet you" name]]
```

or

```
until [
    name: ask "What's your name? " 
    either empty? name [
       true
    ] [
       print ["nice to meet you" name]   
       false
    ]
]
```

or

```
while [not empty? name: ask "What's your name? "][print ["nice to meet you" name]]
```