# Javascript equivalent for Pythons (input())

Tags: javascript

Python:

```
num = int(input('Please enter a number between 0 to 6'))

def someFunction(num):
  # code here
```

How can I do this in JavaScript?

Comment: Javascript in its own right doesn't have this ability. You could use Node.js to achieve the same outcome. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128578/reading-value-from-console-interactively

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp

Comment: where do you expect to run this code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to run the code on browser, you can use window's [`prompt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) method, to take input from user.

```js
let num = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number between 0 to 6"))

function someFunction(num){
  //code here
}
```