# Can't find variable: prompt

Tags: javascript, prompt

```
#!/bin/sh

//Rock, Paper, Scissors

var myChoice = prompt("Rock, Paper, or Scissors?");

var computerChoice = Math.random();

if (computerChoice >= 0 && computerChoice <= .33) 
{
    computerChoice === "rock";
}
else if (computerChoice >=.34 && computerChoice <= .67) 
{
    computerChoice === "paper";
}
else 
{
    computerChoice === "scissors";
};
```

I understand my code to be rudimentary, but I am just beginning with Javacript. I am trying to run this code through the terminal and continue to get the error message "can't find variable: prompt." I am sure there is a simple explanation out there, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: try saving it to file, will it work then?

Comment: `prompt()` is for browsers. I think you're looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120761/how-do-i-get-console-input-in-javascript).

Comment: You also have a semicolon after the `else` which is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

`prompt()` is for browsers. You should use the functions found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey/Introduction_to_the_JavaScript_shell#print.28.5Bexpression_....5D.29) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the prompt function in terminal. It only works in browsers, as it causes a box to popup that the user enters something in. Put it in an html file, and it will work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        // your code goes here, minus that first comment.
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```