# getting int from User Javascript

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, input, terminal

**EDIT** >> readline is not working, getting this message in the terminal "ReferenceError: readline is not defined"

**Javascript noob here**

I'm writing a program where I am trying to get an int from the user. I know how to do this usually within a HTML document however nothing is working within the .js file which I am running in the terminal of my linux machine.

for instance I want to say

```
console.log("enter your number");
//code that collects the int named var yourint
console.log ("your number was " + yourint);
```

It's really battering my brain, because I know I'm just drawing a blank and the solution is obvious.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120761/how-do-i-get-console-input-in-javascript

Comment: so for instance var yourint = readline(); ?

Comment: readline() isn't working

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation of whatever program you are using for a JS shell?

Comment: using node.js Yeah I just can't figure out why it's not working

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html

Answer (score 0):

console.log is outputs a message to a **web console** not a shell

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log

if you are using js24 in linux it will throw an error like

```
typein:1:0 ReferenceError: console is not defined
```

you might want to use `print`

example

```
var input=readline('enter your number');
print('your number was '+input)
```

Comment: It doesn't throw any error, it prints using console.log. The error is in the readline() and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: what shell interpeter are you using?js24?