# call a function every time i return a variable?

Tags: javascript, function

I've noticed that in the Google [text adventure game easter egg](https://techcrunch.com/2018/10/01/theres-a-secret-text-adventure-game-hidden-inside-google-heres-how-to-play-it/) they have a function call everytime you enter in a variable on the javascript console.

How is this done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get console input in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120761/how-do-i-get-console-input-in-javascript)

Comment: @Baruch uh, no, that one is about CLI input in the SpiderMonkey engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work for arbitrary variables. It doesn't work for arbitrary expressions. It only works for those commands that are given (yes, no, north, south, east, west, up, down, grab, why, inventory, use, help, exits, map, and friends).

It doesn't really work for *variables* anyway. What you get when you enter `yes` is the global `window.yes` property - and they have defined a getter for it. This getter will be evaluated, return the string `"yes"`, and asynchronously log the next output to the console.

Comment: `Object.defineProperty(window, "yes", { get() { setTimeout(console.log, 0, "hello"); return "yes"; })`. You can check the code of the easter egg in your debugger, search for `defineProperty`

Comment: You missed a `}` at the end, it would be `Object.defineProperty(window, "yes", { get() { setTimeout(console.log, 0, "hello"); return "yes"; }})`. But thanks for the code!